# Using cx_Oracle with an IN statement (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle, bind-variables

I am trying to pass in parameters into a SQL "IN" statement using cx_Oracle. This gives the correct result:

```
sql = """select * from
           (select level numb from dual connect by level <= 4)
         where numb = :var"""

print([row[0] for row in cur.execute(sql, (1,))])
Output: [1]
```

However I have not been able to figure out how to use an "IN" statement.

```
sql = """select * from
           (select level numb from dual connect by level <= 4)
         where numb in :var"""

print([row[0] for row in cur.execute(sql, (1, 2))])
Output: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I've tried variations of the IN statement, and also with using a dictionary to pass in the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using single values or literals, the `IN` clause in SQL requires values wrapped in parentheses. And since you pass two parameters, include two placeholders within the paranetheses.

```
sql = """select * from
           (select level numb from dual connect by level <= 4)
         where numb in (:1, :2)"""

print([row[0] for row in cur.execute(sql, (1, 2))])
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait -- the exact number of items may not always be known at runtime, so I'm wondering if there is a way to have the IN dynamically recognize one or more values.

Comment: Yes, you can dynamically build prepared SQL statements (like any string in Python) depending on number of items. But this aspect was not mentioned in your above question.

Comment: General solutions and links for dealing with unknown numbers of IN parameters are in https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sqlwherein  I know this is for a different language, but the solutions apply to cx_Oracle, PHP OCI8, and APIs for other languages.